# How do I fo back and deduct the role hiearchy of my trial account?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Apologies for the new question, but I am having trouble understanding the best practices for understanding the recommended role set up for my account. I am auditing what I have created to backwards engineer and correct it on a new warehouse.

So here is the situation:

1. I granted all permissions on all warehouses modify AND usage to the sysadmin.
2. When running worksheets and ./snowsql in parallel, I used the ACCOUNTADMIN for all of the sessions in snowsql.

When I use the Sysadmin to modify the tables that copied the data staged in the warehouse sometimes I have permissions and other times I don't.

I have been sifting through account history with the ACCOUNTADMIN role to view all the grants with the recommended query from the documentation below:

```
select *
from table(information_schema.query_history())
order by start_time;
```

I filtered then by the database and query_id to include grant

```
select *
from table(information_schema.query_history())
where database_name = 'temp_db'
and query_id like '%grant%'
order by start_time;
```

I did this to see if there were any differences in the grants I did between databases in the warehouse. I only set up two warehouses so it was easy to see.

Going forward, Accountadmin is used to create roles, warehouses, and databases.

To prevent the need to do an audit when switching between roles, I want to set future grants on Sysadmin to specific databases in a warehouse for modification and usage, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions to warehouses, database, and all other objects are separate things.  Granting permissions to a warehouse let's that role use or modify a warehouse, but that has nothing at all to do with creating, updating, etc. other objects like databases, schemas, tables, and views.  Also, only the role that OWNS a table can drop or alter a table.  So, you might want to check on the ownership of the tables between SYSADMIN and ACCOUNTADMIN.  As a best practice, ACCOUNTADMIN shouldn't own anything.

It would take quite a bit more information to give you a full rundown of RBAC in Snowflake.  If you are struggling with it, you might want to contact Professional Services at Snowflake and get them to come in and do an overview (QuickStart or Security package) to get you straightened out.